# Tokenizing consecutive lines as paragraphs in markdown with regular expressions. Pattern doesn't work like it looks

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

[According to the CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#paragraphs), text that cannot be classified as any other block element (header, horizontal rule, list, quotes, code blocks) *becomes a paragraph*. That would be a line that does not start with `#` (headers), `-` (horizontal rule, unordered lists), `>` (quotes), numbers (ordered lists) or spaces (code blocks).

So I constructed the following pattern to extract the text:

```
/(?:^|\n{2,})((?:[^#>\-*\d ][^\n]+)+)(?:$|\n{2,})/gm
```

And the following is the chunk of text I'm testing against:

```
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog

Lorem Ipsum

I should match
- I should NOT match

Le sigh

> Why am I matching?
1. Nonononono!
* Aaaagh!
# Stahhhp!

Hello, World!
```

The pattern I made, as I understand it, would match text that is either bounded by 2 newlines, the start or the end of the line. Then it would capture consecutive lines of text that does not begin with `#>\-*\d`. This pattern almost works fine, it matches consecutive lines correctly while splitting lines bound by 2 newlines. **The problem is that it is matching lines starting with `#>\-*\d` when it shouldn't.** What am I doing wrong with this pattern?

You can test this by going to https://regex101.com/ , setting flavor to JavaScript and pasting the above pattern and text.

Comment: `[^#>\-*\d ]` matches newline, `[^\n]` matches `-`.

Comment: Well `((?:[^#>\-*\d ][^\n]+)+)` matches "I should match\n- I should not match" because nothing prevents that single newline followed by the leading `-` from matching.

Comment: Try [`(?:\n{2,}|^)((?:(?![#>*\d -]).+(?:\n|$))+)`](https://regex101.com/r/sDKfs5/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your multiple line parameter is causing this. If you try to examine the region you'd not like to match is matching with only one line at the beginning, not with two. However when you do not use multiline, you may lose other matches as well.

What I suggest use multline option without two or more newlines.

I tried to build a pattern matches your conditions here:

```
/^(?![#>\-*\d ]).+\n?.+/gm
```

I believe this is not the optimized one, but I think it works :)

Edit: refined version is

```
/^(?![#>\-*\d ])((?![#>\-*\d ]).+\n?)+/gm
```

Cheers

Comment: here is refined and saved regex ( regex101.com/r/LxyV4D/3 ) for your case; if this works for you kindly accept this answer as a solution.

Comment: I've since rolled with Wiktor's suggestion and tweaking it from there to handle more edge cases. However, for your answer, the second one works better and is much closer to Wiktor's. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468095/tokenizing-consecutive-lines-as-paragraphs-in-markdown-with-regular-expressions#comment89906770_51468095) solution is good and close, but not quite fitting.

It would not prevent his proposal from catching headers (underlined with `=`) or numbered list or code blocks.

Here is a regular expression that works better. [You can see it in action here](https://regexr.com/5928v).

```
    (?<para_all>
        (?:\n{2,}|^)                # Needs 1 or more new lines or start of string
        (?<para_prefix>[ ]{0,3})    # Possibly some leading spaces, but less than a tab worth
        (?<para_content>
            (?:
                (?!                 # some line content not starting with those exceptions
                    [>*+-=\#]
                    |
                    \d+\.
                    |
                    \`{3,}
                )
            )
            .+
            (?!\n(?:[=-]+|\`{3,}))  # Prevents from catching line followed by header markers
            (?:\n|$)
        )+                          # Allowing multiple occurrences
    )
```